# What's the short way to say "me too" and "me (n)either"?

Tags: grammar, particles

I am just learning about the も　particle and the textbook has examples like this:

> やまださんはがくせいです。わたしもがくせいです。
>   Yamada is a student. I am also a student.

I am wondering whether the repetition of　がくせいです　is really necessary. Can I say something like:

> やまださんはがくせいです。わたしもです。

or maybe

> やまださんはがくせいです。わたしも。

The other question is whether も works with negative statements too. I.e. will the following be grammatical?

> やまださんはせんせいではありません。わたしもせんせいではありません。

And the similar question of the possible contraction of this. Can I say

> やまださんはせんせいではありません。　わたしもではありません。

Can I make it even shorter to say "Neither am I"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following expressions, as appropriate

> 私も。
>
> 私もです。
>
> 私もそうです。
> 私もそうだよ。

all of which roughly mean "me, too". These all work for negative and positive statements, except for a sentence like

> 山田さんは学生じゃありません。

in which case I find it more natural to say

> 私も学生じゃありません。

Comment: I don't think `Ｘもです` is grammatical.

Comment: @istrasci It seems too common to me to call it ungrammatical.

Comment: @snailboat:  "Irregardless" is also common, but that doesn't make it a real word.  To each his own I guess.

Answer (score 3):

You can also say （私も）同じ、（私も）同じく、（私も）一緒等など

Comment: Is it rude to say 私も in a situation where です/ます form is appropriate?

Comment: @Ataraxia You can simply say 私もです。